# How to solve this SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] no connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, connection

I am trying to follow an e-commerce tutorial where I have to create the connection with the database. I am on windows 7 with xampp v3.2.

So I use this : php bin/console generate:doctrine:entity 
 which gives me this error :

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] no connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it

I closed xampp and I still had the same error. So I understand it comes from the configuration; somehow my shell doesn't communicate with my sql server from xampp.

here is my parameters.yml :

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: market
    database_user: sebastian
    database_password: 
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret:
```

and here my config.yml

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@EcommerceBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    #translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
```

I checked for the extension php_pdo_mysql.dl and it is enabled.

I verified the database name, user and password.

here is a netstat :
[netstat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqKmv.jpg)

Comment: According to `parameters.yml` there is no password required for the database.  Was it removed by you or is no password indeed required?

Comment: I removed it, same for secret!

Comment: When creating installing symfony, i gave database_port: 8080 and then i faced this problem, after changing my port to database_port: 3306, it would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your MySQL server is running and that it's using that port (in xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini). Make sure that you're able to connect manually with those credentials as well.

Also, where are you specifying the database driver in your parameters.yml? Normally you should have something like this:

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

And lastly, make sure that you don't have a different parameters.yml file included in your config_dev.yml because Symfony commands, by default, use the dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. 
I have in my.ini 3306 port so it is the good one. I have intalled symfony2.8 and it is working so there is no credentials problems. I also tried to add the line with pdo_mysql but  the error message is an pdo_exception, that means pdo works as well.
I also check config.dev but I don't really know what can be wrong inside. So I show you what it looks like :

```
imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

framework:
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing_dev.yml"
        strict_requirements: true
    profiler: { only_exceptions: false }

web_profiler:
    toolbar: true
    intercept_redirects: false

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            channels: [!event]
        console:
            type:   console
            channels: [!event, !doctrine]
        # uncomment to get logging in your browser
        # you may have to allow bigger header sizes in your Web server configuration
        #firephp:
        #    type:   firephp
        #    level:  info
        #chromephp:
        #    type:   chromephp
        #    level:  info

#swiftmailer:
#    delivery_address: me@example.com
```

thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

i cant connect to mysql on xamppp

install mysql 8  on my system on port 3307

and its worked great with laravel.

if you want please install mysql workbench (instead of phpmyadmin)